# Finding child element by class from parent with pure javascript cross browser

Tags: javascript

Following my code:

```
<div onclick="/*Here I would like to select the child element with the class 'vxf'*/">
   <div class="abc"></div>
   <div class="cir"></div>
   <!--... other elements-->
   <div class="vxf"></div>
   <!--... other elements-->
</div>
<div onclick="/*Here I would like to select the child element with the class 'vxf'*/">
   <div class="abc"></div>
   <div class="cir"></div>
   <!--... other elements-->
   <div class="vxf"></div>
   <!--... other elements-->
</div>
```

How to select the child element with the class "vxf" with pure javascript?

Comment: `this.getElementsByClassName('vxf')`, where `this` refers to the `<div>` element which you are clicking. Anyway what do you need to do? Inside an onclick it's a bad idea, it would be better to do that through a script.

Comment: Will there be multiple elements of that class-name, or can there be only one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pass `this` into your handler...

```
onclick="clickHandler(this)"
```

...and then for maximum browser compatibility, just look in the child nodes:

```
function clickHandler(element) {
    var child;
    for (child = element.firstNode; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.className && child.className.match(/\bvxf\b/)) {
            break; // Found it
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

(Or keep looping and build up an array, if you want all matching children.)

On [most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), another alternative is to use [`querySelector`](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-queryselector) (to find the first) or [`querySelectorAll`](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-queryselectorall) (to get a list) of matching child elements. Sadly, this requires a bit of a trick:

```
function clickHandler(element) {
    var child, needsId;
    needsId = !element.id;
    if (needsId) {
        element.id = "TEMPID____" + (new Date()).getTime();
    }
    child = document.querySelector("#" + element.id + " > .vxf");
    if (needsId) {
        element.id = "";
    }
    // ...
}
```

We have to play the `id` game because we only want direct children (not descendants), and unfortunately you can't use a child combinator without something on the left of it (so `element.querySelector("> .vxf");` doesn't work).

If you didn't care whether it was a direct child or a descendant, then of course it's a lot easier:

```
function clickHandler(element) {
    var child = element.querySelector(".vxf");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: A selector starting with `>` is not a legal selector. It will throw a `SyntaxError` when you pass it to `querySelector`.

Comment: @rvighne: Blast, spoiled by jQuery again. :-) Thanks, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `this.getElementsByClassName('vxf')[0]` in the `div`'s onclick, and you have the element. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nn4GD/)**.

Answer (score 1):

in HTML5 you can use `document.querySelector('.vxf')`

As pointed out in other answers you can also use `document.getElementsByClassName('vxf')` for this specific requirement but the `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()` methods allow you to provide more complex selectors and therefore give you more power, so worth looking at for future.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) for more information.